# Конверсия 400% в analitycs это хорошо?

Tags: seo

Доброго времени. При показателе отказов 45% гугл аналитикс говорит что за месяц коэффициэнт конверсии равен 412% процентов. Как я понимаю понятие конверсии, своими словами это переходы = достигнутые цели. Я так понял что у меня всё прекрасно)))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конверсия не может быть больше 100%, т.к. это отношение целевых пользователей ко всем пользователям. и так как первое является подмножеством второго, то это отношение принимает значения от 0 до 1, или от 0 до 100%